# Large braces for specifying values of variables by condition

Tags: braces, conditionals

How do I produce a conditional expression with large brackets?

**For example:**

X = 0 if a=1, 1 otherwise, with a large left bracket and specifying each condition in a line?

Comment: See also `cases*` environment from mathtools (that interprets the second column as text): https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262081/250119

Answer (score 223, accepted):

The `cases` environment from [amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) does the trick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    X=
    \begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if}\ a=1 \\
      1, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Should there be space in between `a` and `=` ; `=` and `1`?

Comment: @alper: LaTeX knows how to handle the spaces when compiling your source, especially in this case.

Answer (score 42):

Another method, which is especially helpful if one needs to have more control over the items alignment, is the `array` construct.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  X=\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    0, & \text{if}\ a=1 \\
    1, & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of `ll`, one may choose `cc`, `rr`, `rl`, etc. Besides, all the `array` capabilities can be applied here (`\arraycolsep`, `\arraystretch`, `\extrarowheight` by loading the `array` package, etc).

One more alternative could be using the `aligned` environment and adding the pseudo-parenthesis `.`, which can be used to terminate an opening parenthesis `{`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  X = \left \{
  \begin{aligned}
    &0, && \text{if}\ a=1 \\
    &1, && \text{otherwise}
  \end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: should we put `.` after `otherwise`?

Comment: In most cases, yes we should, based on the context.

Answer (score 30):

```
x = \begin{cases}
  0, & \text{if } a = 1, \\
  1, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
```

`amsmath` is needed for `\text`.

Comment: the `&` characters makes the `{cases}` environment break for me in equations written in `\begin{align*}` environments using `amsmath` - so I put spacing in with `\qquad` and similar

Answer (score 5):

[Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) can also be used: $x=[a \neq 1]$.

Comment: Knuth [is a fan of Iverson notation](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9205211), using it heavily in _Concrete Mathematics_ among other publications. BTW, here to match the original question, I think you mean $x = [a \neq 1]$ :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to manually control the size of brace, if `cases` or `\left\{` doesn't provide suitable brace size you want.

```
\begin{math}
\biggl\{
    \begin{array}{l}
        statement1\\
        statement2
    \end{array}
\end{math}
```

You can choose among `\bigl\{` `\Bigl\{` `\biggl\{` `\Biggl\{` to adjust brace size from the smallest to the largest.
[image: Different brace sizes using different methods]

From left to right: `cases` `\left\{` `biggl\{` `Bigl\{`