# Double solution in equation mode

Tags: math-mode, equations

I Want to do give two solutions to an equation, and do something like that:

```
                      / 0
If c = 0    =>    x =
                      \ -b/a
```

[image: What I want]

**Edit**: I've tried the `cases` environment or using `\left\{ ... \right.`, still a good idea but not exactly what wanted.

Comment: How about the `cases` environment from `amsmath`? See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9065/large-braces-for-specifying-values-of-variables-by-condition

Comment: I would suggest you simply `If $c=0$, then $x\in\{0,-b/a \}$`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I think we should point that is similar question with (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9065/large-braces-for-specifying-values-of-variables-by-condition) unless JnxF wants something different

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I tried what you or Jorge Campos suggested, but I don't like it too much what does it looks like.

Comment: @JnxF Well, I haven't seen that lines in math texts ever. I think that's why Torbjørn and G.Medina suggested alternatives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest something simple (without additional symbols that really don't bring anything good to the expression), as the first approach below; I also included something reproducing the image in the original question, but I don't like this option (of course, this is nothing but my personal opinion):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=-0.5ex]\node[inner sep=3pt] (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

\[
\text{If } c=0\text{, then } x\in\{0,-b/a \}.
\]

\[
\text{If } c=0\text{, then } x=\tikzmark{a}\mspace{15mu} 
\begin{array}{l}\tikzmark{b}0 \\ \tikzmark{c}-b/a \end{array}
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw (a) -- (b);
\draw (a) -- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I also think like you. To say that `x` belongs to the set of answers would be most appropriate without having to use "drawings" to indicate something that already has a nomenclature. But in this case, I needed it for educational purposes, and would not include nomenclature. Thanks. Very useful.

Comment: I'm more inclined to use words: "If c=0, then x=0 or x=-b/a". I dislike very much the "two case" notation: x can't be equal to two different things.

Comment: I just used that notation because my students used to use this notation in their written exercises last years, so I don't want to write down a notation nomenclature. I appreciate all your opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

For a change, without tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}

\newcommand\neline{%
\raisebox{1ex}{\rotatebox{-20}{\ensuremath\diagup}}}
\newcommand\seline{%
\raisebox{-1ex}{\rotatebox{20}{\ensuremath\diagdown}}}
\newlength{\mylength}
\settowidth{\mylength}{\neline}

\begin{document}


\[
\text{If } c=0\text{, then } x = \neline\kern-\mylength\seline \begin{array}{l}0 \\ -b/a \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

As suggested by **Enrico**, it is better to use `\makebox[0pt][l]{\neline}`, then we don't have to measure the width. Further we can merge `\neline` and `\seline` to make a single macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}
%
\newcommand\neline{%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{1ex}{\rotatebox{-20}{\ensuremath\diagup}}}
\raisebox{-1ex}{\rotatebox{20}{\ensuremath\diagdown}}}
%
\begin{document}    
\[
\text{If } c=0\text{, then } x = \neline \begin{array}{l}0 \\ -b/a \end{array}
\]    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use, in `math` mode, the command `cases` from `amsmath`. What you want could be something like this:

```
x = \begin{cases} 0,  \\ 
    -\frac{b}{a},  \end{cases}
```

You might want to add text:

```
x = \begin{cases} 0 , \mbox{when ...}  \\
    -\frac{b}{a}, \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
    \mbox{If } c=0\mbox{, then } x=\mathop{\left\langle\phantom{x^2}\right.}^1_{-\frac{b}{a}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could also consider using the "cases" environment (but leaving the condition part empty).

```
\[
\text{If } c=0\text{, then } x=\begin{cases} 
0  & \\ 
-\frac{b}{a} &  
\end{cases}
\]
```