# Left brace including several lines in eqnarray

Tags: equations, braces

How is it possible to make a brace and have something like this in a `eqnarray` block?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.  (But you should know this? ;) Could you also add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?)

Comment: See [`\eqnarray` vs `\align`](http://goo.gl/3R7Ln) on why not to use `eqnarray`. Then [Large braces for specifying values of variables by condition](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9065/5764) as a possible duplicate, which suggests using `cases` from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Here's a sample document without the use of `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \[
    \alpha(x)=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  x\\
                  \frac{1}{1+e^{-kx}}\\
                  \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}
                \end{array}
              \right.
  \]
\end{document}
```

or one with `amsmath`'s `cases` environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \alpha(x)=\begin{cases}
               x\\
               \frac{1}{1+e^{-kx}}\\
               \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}
            \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```