# How to write commands for cases?

Tags: math-mode, cases

For writing cases like a definition of a function having two or more conditions compiled by large braces ({), do I have to use `\begin{equation}` and `\begin{cases}` within, or there is some other command which can be used even inside `$$ ... $$` ?

Comment: Probably [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122779/27635) of mine can help you (note that it's better to replace `$$ ... $$` with `\[ ... \]`).

Comment: Do you know [Math Mode](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathmode) by Herbert Voß? It has a few example of cases structures. BTW: you shouldn't use `$$ ... $$` in a LaTeX document: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to