# How to write an array of equations without using eqnarray?

Tags: align, arrays

I heard that it is recommended to use align or array. But how should I do so to replace the use of eqnarray?
Thank you very much.

Comment: `align` is a more or less exact replacement, just take care to use `&=` rather than `&=&` when switching from `eqnarray` to `align`

Comment: thanks! how about    array    ?

Comment: `array` is not the same kind of environment at all: it is not for setting display equations it is for settings arrays/matrices within a math environment such as `align` or `equalign`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an `eqnarray` environment, you might write:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
a &=& b\\
c &=& d
\end{eqnarray}
```

With an `align` environment (be sure to load the `amsmath` package), you'd write

```
\begin{align}
a &= b\\
c &= d
\end{align}
```

The only significant change -- other than the change in the name of the environment, of course -- is that one writes `&=` (*not* `=&`!) when using an `align` environment in order to bring about alignment on the `=` symbol.

Comment: @kwyip - I wouldn't use an `array`, for 3 reasons. First, the cells in an `array` are typeset in "text-style math" mode by default, whereas the material in an `align` environment is set in "display-style math" mode. Second, the spacing between rows is much tighter (too tight, in many cases) in an `array`. Third, with `array` you don't get the easy ability to number individual lines of a multi-line equation. You may also want to look into the `IEEEeqnarray` environment that's provided by the [IEEEtrantools](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/) package.

Comment: I want to produce big parathesis like this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122778/left-brace-including-several-lines-in-eqnarray   How do I do this with "align" instead of "array"? Thanks.

Comment: @kwyip - That's a new question. Please post it as a new question, to give it a chance to be seen by more people. Thanks.

Comment: Could you give me advice on that new question?

Comment: @kwyip - I honestly don't know how to generate the construct mentioned in the newer posting using an `align` environment; `align` seems utterly unsuitable to the task. Why don't you want to use a `cases` environment for that construct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `equationarray` environment which is loaded with the `eqnarray` package. It is a math environment that mimics the behavior of the `array` environment which is more suited for text. It also adds a different number to each equation. Unlike the `eqnarray` environment, you can align more than 3 columns of information.

Simply add

```
\usepackage{eqnarray}
```

to the preamble. Then you can use `equationarray` exactly as you would use an `array`:

```
\begin{equationarray}{rclrcl}
a &=& b & c &=& d\\
c &=& d & a &=& b
\end{equationarray}
```