# Using "align" instead of "array" in an array of equations

Tags: math-mode, align, arrays

I want to produce big parenthesis like this: [Left brace including several lines in eqnarray](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122778/22413)
How do I do this with `align` instead of `array`? I do not want to use `eqnarray` though. Thanks.

Comment: Why `align`? Is it because you want the components of the `cases` environment numbered? For that you can use `numcases`. Could please describe *exactly* what you want?

Comment: spacing between rows are tighter if i use array

Comment: If you want the rows to be spaced tightly, definitely do *not* use an `align` environment, since it'll typeset the material in display math mode.

Comment: Yes, the appearances are different. I want the rows to be spaced widely, so I hope to use align environment. Also, there are multiple advantages to use align over array (described in multiple posts in stack-exchange here).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `empheq`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[left={\alpha(x)= \empheqlbrace}]{align}
               &  x\\
               & \frac{1}{1+e^{-kx}}\\
               & \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I not use any outside package to produce the above using align? Thank you.

Comment: That means I need something *normal like "\begin {align} ..... \end {align}", not importing subsidiary package "\begin {empheq}{align}....\end{empheq}".

Comment: @kwyip Use `numcases` then

Comment: how about not using "numcases" or "cases"? I have to use align. Thank you.