# Bracket in subequations

Tags: brackets, subequations

I have two equations, places inside subequations. How can I put the bracket { on the left side of these subequations?

[image]

P.S.I tried cases, but it doesn't work there - error "Missing $ inserted"

```
\begin{subequations} \begin{cases}
\begin{equation} subeq.1 \end{equation}
\begin{equation} subeq.2 \end{equation}
\end{cases} \end{subequations}
```

Comment: Should be on this question:
[Link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122778/left-brace-including-several-lines-in-eqnarray)

Comment: I suppose [Separate labels in cases](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31951) is what you're after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stealing @Bernard's example, i've expanded it to show a multi-line situation.
the `[t]` is a necessary option on the `aligned` block to keep the block
from being centered vertically, but unfortunately it also has the effect of
placing the equation number on the top line of that component.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
    x &  = \begin{aligned}[t]
           & y + z + \text{something to make this wider}\\
           & + \text{more stuff to produce multiple lines}
           \end{aligned}\\
    a^2 &  =  b + c
  \end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

one other comment ... bernard's answer uses "unicode" superscripts.
doesn't always work (and there aren't unicode superscripts for greek letters or really anything but digits), so it's not recommended to use those in math.

but otherwise, bernard's answer is solid.

Comment: I edited Bernard's answer; apparently he's using a smart editor that maps those characters into “real” TeX style exponents.

Comment: Thanks, for the solution @Barbara.
I've figured out that I couldn't understand Bernard's solution because I didn't realise how align and aligned work.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `empheq` environment The homonymous package load `amsmath` and `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
    x &  = y + z\\
    a^{2} &  =  b^{2} + c^{2}
  \end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Bernard.
Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work for big formulas, when it is nessesary to use  \begin{equation} \end{equation}.

What do I need to change to make the code below works?

\begin{subequations}

  \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}

      \begin{equation}

      x   = y + z

      \end{equation}

      \begin{equation}

      a²   =  b² + c²

      \end{equation} 

        \end{empheq}

\end{subequations}

Comment: You have several subequations, and don't want them to be aligned? Replace `align` with `gather`. `empheq` works with all amsmath environments (not with the subenvironments such as `aligned` or `gathered`).

Comment: If I replace align with gather I still can't use \begin{equation} \end{equation}  --- LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter. 

\begin{subequations}  \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{gather}    
  \begin{equation} subeq.1  \end{equation}     
  \begin{equation} subeq.2  \end{equation}    
  \end{empheq}  \end{subequations}

Comment: Did I misunderstand you @Bernard? 
 
Also, I do want my equations to be aligned, but I have long subequations (couple lines long). Therefore I can't use {align} and \\ for each new lines) as you wrote in your first answer, because in this case every new line will be recognised as a new formula and obtain a number.

Comment: For the last but one comment: if you use `gather`, you don't use `equation`. The latter is for *one-lined* equations, the former for a group of equations.  `gather` with one equation is the same as `equation`.

Comment: Could you post an explicit code? What you want is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

With the `amsmath` package:

```
\[
  left text \begin{cases}
               sub1 & 1\\
               sub2 & 2
            \end{cases}
\]
```

Comment: I think the OP wants each case to be numbered separately.

Comment: Yes, @TorbjørnT, I want each case to be numbered separately.

Comment: This?
`\[
left text 
\begin{cases}
subequation & 1\\
subequation & 2
\end{cases}
\]`

I added both `& Number` to my answer.

Comment: @SunnyBastard *Automatic* numbering, and your way won't help for cross-references either. See Bernard's answer, or [Separate labels in cases](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31951)