# Complicated Pseudocode in Latex - Need assistance

Tags: algorithmicx, pseudocode

I am trying to create a complicated pseudocode as shown below:

[image]

**My attempt:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Self-Quotient algorithm}\label{euclid}

  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
  %-------------- Input & Output -----------------
  \State \textbf{Input:} Input image \textbf{I}, Gaussian filter \textbf{G} of size \textit{s}$\times$\textit{s}
  \State \textbf{Output:} Self-Quotient image \textbf{Q}

  %--------------- for loop -----------------------
  \For{\textbf{all} pixel \textbf{I}$(x,y)$}
       \State Consider a window \textbf{W} of size s$\times$s around \textbf{I}$(x,y)$
       \State Compute the anisotropic filter $\textbf{F}_{\textbf{W}(x,y)}$ at the location $(x,y)$

       \State $\textbf{F}_{\textbf{W}(x,y)}$ = \{ \textbf{G}$(x,y)$  if \textbf{W}$(x,y)\geq$ Mean(\textbf{W})
       \State $\textbf{Z}(x,y)$ = $\Sigma\Sigma( \textbf{F}_{\textbf{W}(x,y)} \circ \textbf{W}(x,y) )$
       \State Compute the weight \textbf{w}
       \State \textit{w} = ( \textit{s} $\times$ \textit{s} ) $\times \Sigma\Sigma \textbf{F}_\textbf{W}$
  \EndFor

  %----------- Remaining text ----------------
  \State Compute Self-Quotient image \textbf{Q} and correct singularities
  \State \textbf{Q} = 
  \State Adjust histogram and normalize image \textbf{Q}

  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

I am not able to do a few things:

1. Remove line numbers on the left
2. curly braces in line 6: statement incomplete
3. size of Sigma in line 7 not like what I want. Also line 9 same problem.
4. creating the 2nd-last line (line 12)

Could someone please fix this? I have tried a lot!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following provides the output that you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,amsmath,algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Self-Quotient algorithm}\label{euclid}

  \begin{algorithmic}[0]
  %-------------- Input & Output -----------------
  \State \textbf{Input:} Input image \textbf{I}, Gaussian filter \textbf{G} of size \textit{s}$\times$\textit{s}
  \State \textbf{Output:} Self-Quotient image \textbf{Q}

  %--------------- for loop -----------------------
  \For{\textbf{all} pixel $\textbf{I}(x,y)$}
       \State Consider a window \textbf{W} of size $s \times s$ around $\textbf{I}(x,y)$
       \State Compute the anisotropic filter $\textbf{F}_{\textbf{W}(x,y)}$ at the location $(x,y)$

       \State $\textbf{F}_{\text{\textbf{W}(x,y)}} = \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
           \textbf{G}(x,y) & \text{if $\textbf{W}(x,y) \geq \text{Mean}(\textbf{W})$} \\
           0               & \text{if $\textbf{W}(x,y) < \text{Mean}(\textbf{W})$}
         \end{array}\right.$
       \State $\textbf{Z}(x,y)$ = $\sum\sum ( \textbf{F}_{\text{\textbf{W}(x,y)}} \circ \textbf{W}(x,y) )$
       \State Compute the weight $w$
       \State $w = ( s \times s ) \times \sum\sum \textbf{F}_{\text{\textbf{W}}}$
       \State $w = \tfrac{1}{w}$
  \EndFor

  %----------- Remaining text ----------------
  \State Compute Self-Quotient image \textbf{Q} and correct singularities
  \State $\textbf{Q} = \tfrac{\textbf{I}}{w\textbf{Z}}$
  \State Adjust histogram and normalize image \textbf{Q}

  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Regarding your outstanding issues, here are the remedies:

1. Use `\begin{algorithmic}[0]`;
2. Use `\left\{\begin{array}{cl} ... \end{array}\right.` or the [`cases` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9065/5764) supplied by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath);
3. Use `\sum`, not `\Sigma`;
4. Use `\frac{<numerator>}{<denominator>}` or `\tfrac` (also from `amsmath`).

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks also for explaining the reasoning! Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For issue 2 you have no ending `\}` (below is what you have)

```
\{ \textbf{G}$(x,y)$  if \textbf{W}$(x,y)\geq$ Mean(\textbf{W})
```

You are missing an ending `\}`  Also, I would write this as:

```
$\mathbf{F}_{\mathbf{W}(x,y)} = \{\mathbf{G}(x,y)  \text{ if} \mathbf{W}(x,y)\geq \text{Mean}(\mathbf{W})\}$
```

This way you didn't have to enter math mode so many times.

For issue 3 (if you want bigger) use `\displaystyle`; that is, `$\displaystyle\Sigma\Sigma`

For issue 4 `$\mathbf{Q} = \frac{\mathbf{I}}{w\mathbf{z}}$`

For issue 1, is line numbering part of the package?

With `algorithm2e` not sure with just `algorithm`, you can do

```
{\LinesNumberedHidden
\begin{algorithm}
your stuff
\end{algorithm}}
```

Comment: issue 1: I am not sure, just need them to be removed //// issue 2: please look at corresponding part of actual pseudocode. It has 2 equations inside one big curly brace. I want that. //// issue 3: \displaystyle still printing same small sigma //// issue 4: works now!