# Multiple results for equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, brackets, braces

How do I define a equation e.g. `x +y` that shall be true for e.g. `<5` and `>0` in one equation? I was thinking of using a large brace, but I can't find any example of how to achieve this.

Comment: `\begin{cases} j & k \\ u & p \end{cases}` ??

Comment: Thanks :-) I'm a beginner, didn't know about that command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Large braces for specifying values of variables by condition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9065/large-braces-for-specifying-values-of-variables-by-condition)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \[ x+y = \begin{cases} \mbox{true,} & \mbox{if } 0 < x < 5 \\ \mbox{false,} & \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases} \]

\end{document}
```

would give you:

[image]

Comment: also I'm not sure if there should be commas after `true` or `false` (in English) but there should be comma after `<5` and perhaps a dot after `otherwise`.

Answer (score 9):

Another solution with `\dcases*` from `mathtools`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ 
  x+y = 
  \begin{dcases*} 
  \text{true,} & if  $0 < x < 5$ \\ 
  \text{false,} & otherwise 
  \end{dcases*} 
\]

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]