# How to write conditional equations with one-sided curly brackets in Mnemosyne?

Tags: math-mode

I want to write conditional equations with one-sided curly brackets in Spaced Repetition software [Mnemosyne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemosyne_(software)). I have latex installed. I want an equation somewhat similar to the following

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I believe you are looking for `cases` environment from the package `amsmath`, as explained for instance here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9065/large-braces-for-specifying-values-of-variables-by-condition

Comment: Oh, I now realize that you probably ask about how to do this in a 3rd party software, right? I'm afraid that in that case, it is off-topic here.

Comment: If you are really just searching for LaTeX-code, it would be `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{mathtools}\begin{document}\[f(x)=\begin{cases*}\frac{x^2-x}{x},&if $x\geq1$\\0,&otherwise\end{cases*}\]\end{document}`

Comment: @yo' -- looking at the documentation for the mnemosyne project, it *does* have the ability to use latex code ("need latex and dvipng installed").  documented here: http://mnemosyne-proj.org/help/adding-media.php

Answer (score 4):

if i read the instructions on this page (http://mnemosyne-proj.org/help/adding-media.php)
correctly, here's what you'd input:

```
<$$>
 f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    x^2 - x, & \text{if $x \ge 1$}\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
</$$>
```

whether this actually works depends on whether mnemosyne includes `amsmath` in its
complement of recognized packages.  but if it does not, then it would not be unreasonable
to request the developers to add it.  better yet would be to add `mathtools` which loads
`amsmath`, corrects some known bugs, and adds useful extensions.

Comment: Tried that but it's not working.I found [this](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/Matrices.html) page, on modifying the last code to my requirement, I got the following result :[image from mnemosyne](http://imgur.com/5NUN1Fn)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution on [this page](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/Matrices.html). Modifying it to my requirement, the following is the result in Mnemosyne:

[image]

and this is the code written to achieve that

```
<$$>
f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         \frac{x^2 -x}{2}, & \mbox{if $x \geq 1$};\\
        0 ,& \mbox{otherwise}.\end{array} \right. 
</$$>
```

Comment: @andrew swann: can you explain me how you made the code look neat?

Comment: Just mark the code region and then press the `{}` button above the input box - it indents the whole region by 4 spaces on each line, which is interpreted by markdowan as input that should be formatted as code.