# Typesetting a function defined by case analysis

Tags: math-mode, cases

Can any one suggess me the code to write this equation in LaTeX.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried anything before asking for some help? If it's the case, you should shows us what you've done `;-)`

Comment: @FarhanRaza If one of the below answers solved your problem, please accept one answer, so the question is marked solved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Large braces for specifying values of variables by condition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9065/large-braces-for-specifying-values-of-variables-by-condition)

Answer (score 27):

You can make use of [`mathtools`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) and its `cases*` environment.

The environments `cases*` and `dcases*` handles the second column as text, so you wont have to manually "escape" mathmode to typeset the text correctly. The `dcases*` variant use displaystyle math in the first column, which will make no difference in your situation. See [section 3.4.3 in the package documentation](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf#page=18) for more details.

If you want to remove the equation number (1), you can use `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}` instead of `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    L =
    \begin{cases*}
      (0 + 1)^{*} & if $P = \mathit{NP}$ \\
      \phi        & otherwise
    \end{cases*}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I would suggest to use `equation*` instead of replacing `equation` by `\[ \]`. It is easier and much easier if you want to put numbers back.

Comment: There are quite a few differences between this output and the question image: 1) The left part was originally centered and not left-aligned and 2) the `otherwise` wasn't aligned with `if P = NP`.  It would be informative to provide a way to match the example output more closely.

Comment: @Bakuriu The question is how to write the given equation in LaTeX, not how to achieve an identical output. Both equations are the same, which I consider to be the answer to the question. Also, the left part isn't centered; the last line is centered, with the space evenly distributed before, between and after the text.

Answer (score 18):

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  L =
  \begin{cases}
    (0 + 1)* & \text{if $P = \mathit{NP}$} \\
    \emptyset & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]