# How can I align equation in a big brace?

Tags: equations, brackets, braces

I want to write the following equation:

[image]

For that I wrote a code:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}   
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}} 
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
w_{i} =  \Bigg\{1;\hspace{0.25cm} if\hspace{0.25cm} 0.25N \leq i \leq 0.75N \\
                            0.5;\hspace{0.25cm} otherwise\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: You could use the `cases` environment. (`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[  
w_{i}=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } 0.25N \leq i \leq 0.75N\\
        0.5, & \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}

` should get you started.

Comment: See also: [Typesetting a function defined by case analysis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262079/134144)

Comment: It's perfect. Thanks. You can add it as an answer.

Comment: Since your question is basically identical to this one [Typesetting a function defined by case analysis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262079/typesetting-a-function-defined-by-case-analysis) I voted to close yours as a duplicate.