# Displaying two conditions in one equation

Tags: math-mode, equations

I was trying to type the following equation, which 2 conditions answer for P(t). However, I don't get what I want. I do appreciate it if someone could please help me. I also required a single equation number for this equation as shown.

`\begin{equation} \label{eq31} \begin{aligned}P(t) &= \!\begin{aligned}\Big\{[A(t)-B(t)].\Delta t] &\forall t,  when  A(t)>B(t) \\ {} 0  \forall t  when A(t)\leq B(t)  \end{aligned} \\ \end{aligned} \end{equation}`
[[image: equation]]

Comment: Perhaps also post an image of what do you get.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typesetting a function defined by case analysis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262079/typesetting-a-function-defined-by-case-analysis)

Answer (score 3):

The environment `cases` from `amsmath` is made to write such conditions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq31} 
P(t) = \begin{cases}
    [A(t)-B(t)].\Delta t] & \text{when } A(t)>B(t) \\ 
    0                     & \text{when } A(t)\leq B(t)
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```