# How to remove the equation numbering from the given solution?

Tags: equations, miktex, texmaker, brackets

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9068/89690

I understand the part of how it works but I want the equation numbering (at the extreme right) to be removed. How to achieve this?

Comment: \begin{equation*} \end{equation*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to use `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}`.

In general adding a `*` often gets rid of numbering e.g., in `align`, `gather`, `multline` the `*` works also.