# Formula in Math

Tags: math-mode

How do you write this in latex? [image]

and this [image]

Comment: Please do yourself a favour and have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner instead of asking a separate question about each and every equation.

Comment: Please improve the title of your question to match its contents, so that it could be searchable. For example, use keywords: large braces, left braces with multi lines equation, etc.. 
For your second equation, you can find some help in this answer:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9065/large-braces-for-specifying-values-of-variables-by-condition
Your first equation is just straight forward.

Answer (score 4):

First you must read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). However...

The code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  [-\pi, \pi] &= [a_1, b_1] \cup [a_2 - (b_2 - a_1), b_2 - (b_2 - a_1)],  \\
  h_k(x)      &= \begin{cases}
                   g(x),               & a_1 \leq x \leq b_1  \\
                   g(x - (b_2 - a_1)), & a_2 \leq x \leq b_2 .
                 \end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]