# How to write cases in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, cases

I want to write following system of equation in my paper, but I don't know how:
[image]

Here is a code that I've tried, but it does not work:

```
R\geqslant R_t \equiv \begin{cases} \frac{r_{t+1} (1-W(k_t)}{f'(k{t+1}    
\lambda} &\mbox{if } k_t < K(\lambda) \\ 
\frac{r_{t+1}}{f'(k_{t+1})} & \mbox{if } k_t\geqslant K(\lambda) 
\end{cases}
```

Any suggestions will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Excuse me but the code is different from the image. Have I understood well?

Comment: Consider accepting one of the provided answers if your question is solved (check mark on the left hand side of the answers).

Comment: I don't understand what you were having trouble with.  The only error I got compiling was about `\geqslant`.  What about didn't work?  Or were you wanting to get something closer to your image than you have?  I would say that your code gives a better output than that image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Large braces for specifying values of variables by condition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9065/large-braces-for-specifying-values-of-variables-by-condition)

Answer (score 15):

I would load the `mathtools` package, which is a superset of the `amsmath` package, and employ that package's `dcases*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'dcases*' env.
\begin{document}
\[
R\ge R_t \equiv
\begin{dcases*}
\frac{r_{t+1}}{f'(k_{t+1})}\frac{1-W(k_t)}{\lambda} 
   & if  $k_t < K(\lambda)$\,, \\[1ex]
\frac{r_{t+1}}{f'(k_{t+1})} 
   & if $k_t\ge K(\lambda)$\,.
\end{dcases*}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this command better than the usual `cases` command?

Comment: @knzhou - I wouldn't say that `dcases` is necessarily better than `cases`, certainly not in the sense of it being *always and everywhere" better than `cases`. The `d` in `dcases` denotes "automatic **d**isplay-style math mode. It's handy if one has to typeset expressions such as `\frac`, which might look a whole lot better when rendered in display-style math mode rather than in text-style math mode. Conversely, `cases` is much more parsimonious, space-wise, than `dcases`. If conserving space is an important criterion, by all means go with `cases`.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! I was just asking in case `cases` had been declared obsolete by people in the know for some reason, like how `\[ ... \]` is supposed to be strictly better than `$$ ... $$`.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to TeX.SE. Here my (fast) proposal from your original code:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[R\geqslant R_t \equiv \begin{cases} \dfrac{r_{t+1} (1-W(k_t))}{f'(k{t+1}    
\lambda)} &\mbox{if } k_t < K(\lambda) \\
&\\
\dfrac{r_{t+1}}{f'(k_{t+1})} & \mbox{if } k_t\geqslant K(\lambda) 
\end{cases}\] 
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** By correct comment of @Yorgos:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
R\geqslant R_t \equiv 
\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{r_{t+1} (1-W(k_t))}{f'(k{t+1} \lambda)} 
    & \text{if } k_t < K(\lambda) \\
&\\  % blank row
\dfrac{r_{t+1}}{f'(k_{t+1})} 
    & \text{if } k_t\geqslant K(\lambda) 
\end{cases}
\] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: i don't think that `mbox` is necessary, since `&` aligns. also i prefer `equation` environment, since it allows for numbering the equation

Comment: @Yorgos I accept your suggestion correctly. I have only taken the code from the user. :(

Comment: I believe that the `k{t+1}` term in the first denominator should be changed to `k_{t+1}`.

Comment: @Mico Thank you very much for edit and all ....You're right for you comment.