# How to put numbers above each other within bracket

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I want to get the following formula:

[image]

How can I get a curly bracket in which I have two lines on top of each other?

Comment: Also: [Large braces for specifying values of variables by condition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9065/82917)

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
\documentclass[margin=8pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    =\left\{ 
    \begin{array}{cc}
        1 & tf_{ij}>0  \\
        0 & tf_{ij}=0
    \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]