# How do I use curly braces to typeset the definition of Graham Number?

Tags: math-mode, cases, braces

This is the definition of Graham's Number.

[image]

How do I subdivide the text in the bracket, as shown?

Comment: I've voted to reopen the question as it would appear to call for nothing more than a straightforward use of the `cases` environment provided by the `amsmath` package.

Comment: @Mico Yes, exactly. Thank you!

Comment: Is duplicate of [conditionals - Large braces for specifying values of variables by condition - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9065/large-braces-for-specifying-values-of-variables-by-condition) anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[g_n =
  \begin{cases}
    3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3 & n=1\\
    3\uparrow^{g_{n-1}}3 & n\geq2, n\in\mathbb{N}
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling with that "cases" environment, but now it's all good